# Automate input to the shell of a program

Tags: shell, docker, mongodb

These days many programs like mongodb, docker etc, have there own shell i.e., if you type `docker -i` it opens an interactive shell (similarly with mongo and other programs).

Is there a way to automate input to these shells via Uunix shell scripts? Or any other way a Unix shell could communicate with the shells of these programs?

Comment: `docker` doesn't really have it's own shell. It just executes bash inside of the container. For `mongodb`, use the CLI client or a library. If you have something where all other options are exhausted, as a last resort you can use `expect`.

Comment: Yepp docker doesnt have its open its own shell but that of its OS in its container.. I am having a look at expect but isn't there any other way like  pipe or something ?

Answer (score 0):

While I am not in a position to try it the following should allow the redirection you require

```
$ docker -i < $(ls -lah)
```